# Symfony form validation sets invalid sub-forms as valid, when used doctrine ORM validation constraints

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, orm, doctrine

**Situation**

I have a form type with sub-forms that i render on frontend with tabs, so only one sub-form (as tab) can be shown at once. Because of that, when errors on different tabs happened, i popup a dialog that shows the errors. By looping recursively the final request-handled form object.

The validation constraints are written in the form type. This results a final form object that i can loop, and the sub forms are indicated as **valid=false** when really happened an error there.

**Goal**

I want to outsource all validation constraints into the ORM mapping of the entity.

**Problem**

When i outsource all validation errors into the ORM mapping, the final form object contains sub-forms that are all **valid=true** even tough its inner form widgets were submitted with an validation error. Only the uppermost form level is valid=false.

This phenomen occurs when building all sub forms without-, and also with event subscribers.

I want that the sub forms also are setted as invalid on the final form object, when in there occurs errors, how can i achieve this?

- Symfony 2.8.3
- Doctrine ORM 2.5.4

**EDIT**

Using **error_bubbling** did not work for me. Maybe i didn't use it correctly?

With this input:

```
form
{{ dump(form) }}

form.vars.valid
{{ dump(form.vars.valid) }}

form.vars.errors
{{ dump(form.vars.errors) }}

form.children.sections.vars.errors
{{ dump(form.children.sections.vars.errors) }}

form.children.sections.vars.valid
{{ dump(form.children.sections.vars.valid) }}

form.children.sections.children.general.vars.errors
{{ dump(form.children.sections.children.general.vars.errors) }}

form.children.sections.children.general.vars.valid
{{ dump(form.children.sections.children.general.vars.valid) }}

form.children.sections.children.general.children.lang.vars.valid
{{ dump(form.children.sections.children.general.children.lang.vars.valid) }}

form.children.sections.children.general.children.lang.vars.errors
{{ dump(form.children.sections.children.general.children.lang.vars.errors) }}
```

I recieve this output:

```
form
FormView {#12833 ▼
  +vars: array:28 [▶]
  +parent: null
  +children: array:3 [▶]
  -rendered: false}

form.vars.valid
false

form.vars.errors
FormErrorIterator {#12832 ▼
  -form: Form {#5652 ▶}
  -errors: array:1 [▶]
}

form.children.sections.vars.errors
FormErrorIterator {#12837 ▼
  -form: Form {#5649 ▶}
  -errors: []
}

form.children.sections.vars.valid
true

form.children.sections.children.general.vars.errors
FormErrorIterator {#12841 ▼
  -form: Form {#5498 ▶}
  -errors: []
}

form.children.sections.children.general.vars.valid
true

form.children.sections.children.general.children.lang.vars.valid
true

form.children.sections.children.general.children.lang.vars.errors
FormErrorIterator {#12851 ▼
  -form: Form {#2009 ▶}
  -errors: []
}
```

The error i generate in **form.children.sections.children.general.children.lang**. I want that from this position, the recursive parents have **...valid=false**.

I tried **error_bubbling=true** on following situations, with the same dump results.

- All form types with the **lang** widget itself
- All form types without the **lang** widget itself
- Only the **lang** widget

What did i wrong, or i need another workaround?

**EDIT 2**

So now i tried **error_bubbling=false** on following situations, with **still** the same dump results.

- All form types with the **lang** widget itself
- All form types without the **lang** widget itself
- Only the **lang** widget

Here some snippets

The entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Myvendor\CoreBundle\Entity\MyItemRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="myitem")
 */
class MyItem
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var \Myvendor\CoreBundle\Entity\Language
     *
     * @Assert\Type("Myvendor\CoreBundle\Entity\Languag")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Myvendor\CoreBundle\Entity\Language")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="language_id", nullable=true, referencedColumnName="langid")
     */
    private $lang;

/**
 * Set lang
 *
 * @param \Myvendor\CoreBundle\Entity\Language $lang
 *
 * @return MyItem
 */
public function setLang(\Myvendor\CoreBundle\Entity\Language $lang = null)
{
    $this->lang = $lang;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get lang
 *
 * @return \Myvendor\CoreBundle\Entity\Language
 */
public function getLang()
{
    return $this->lang;
}
/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}



}
```

The initial form type

```
class MyItemType extends AbstractMyvendorType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
         $sections = $builder->create('sections', 'form', array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'label' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'data-sections' => '1'
            ),
            'error_bubbling' => false
          ));
        $builder->add($sections);
        $builder->addEventSubscriber(new DynamicSubforms());
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'error_bubbling' => false
        ));
    }
}
```

The event subscriber

```
class DynamicSubforms implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'onPreSetData'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Adding subtypes, depending on the myitem type.
     *
     * @author FPI
     * @param FormEvent $event            
     */
    public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        /**
         *
         * @var $data \Myvendor\CoreBundle\Entity\MyItem
         * @var $form \Symfony\Component\Form\Form
         */
        $data = $event->getData();
        $steptype = $data->getType();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $options = $form->getConfig()->getOptions();
        $sections = $form->get('sections');

        $default_section_options = array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'data' => $data
        );
        // Every steptype has section "general"
        $sections->add('general', GeneralType::class, array_merge($default_section_options, array(
            'label' => 'general',
            'error_bubbling' => false
        )));

    }
}
```

The sub form type

```
class GeneralType extends AbstractType
{

    protected $em;

    protected $choiceOption;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, ChoiceOption $choice_option)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->choiceOption = $choice_option;
    }

    /*
     * Here are set the static options for each widget.
     * The dynamic options on specific widgets are specified in the event subscriber.
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @author FPI
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        /* Language */
        $builder->add('lang', 'entity', array(
            'label' => 'language',
            'class' => 'MyvendorCoreBundle:Language',
               'error_bubbling' => false
        ));

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'error_bubbling' => false
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-bubbling

Comment: I used this already, but i could not achieve my goal with it. I edited my post. Maybe i did something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with *This phenomen occurs when building all sub forms without-*

Comment: @Manolo When i builded the form the first time, i programmed all dynamic stuff in the type class itself. Then i had the possibility to let evaluate my form type from a **SensioLabs employee** (payed workshop). I expelled him also this problem. He said that when using form events (as clean dynamic symfony forms should be), the errors should behave like i wanted. But they behave on the same way, with- and whitout using form events.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the errors to be passed to the form parent, you should set `error_bubbling` to false, as `error_bubbling` is false by default **unless the form is compound** ([error_bubbling](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-bubbling)).

Comment: Does it help @FabianPicone?

Comment: Setting **error_bubbling** to **false** did not help, see my **EDIT 2** above

Comment: Well, if you set `mapped` to `false`, errors won't be captured, I think.